# How to play video streames recived from server live

Tags: ios, uiimage, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation, cgimage

I heard that to play live stream video we need to give the path or url of video to mpmovieplayer controller, It's ok but here in my app we need to play live brodcasted video but our server team is sending data in the form of buffers (images).each time we request they send a buffer .i'm not getting how to play that can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good example to start with

http://www.gdcl.co.uk/iOS/encoderdemo.zip